# PostgreSQL foreign function

Tags: postgresql, cluster-computing, foreign-data-wrapper

I have not tested this, but want to know how it would work. I want to create three databases on three nodes. Each will be the same (schema, functions) but with different data.

I want to call a function from each of the database and join them eg:

```
select server1.very_time_expensive_function(1,2) + 
       server2.very_time_expensive_function(2,3) +
       server3.very_time_expensive_function(3,4);
```

But foreign functions cannot be created. Just [foreign tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigntable.html)

What would you recomend?

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PL/Proxy

Comment: I found out when I `CREATE VIEW function_view AS SELECT very_time_expensive_function_without_args() AS col` on servers and then on local server `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE func_viewX (col integer) SERVER serverX options (table_name 'function_view')` then I can `SELECT func_view1.col + func_view2.col + func_view3.col`. But I dont know how to send args to the function in view.

Comment: You could have a look at postgresql_fdw to include your other databases into one ... Having a view on the included ones, you could do something like that. But maybe hadoop or something else would be a better choice maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send args to a function from a view unless those arguments either come from the rows or are specified at view creation time.  So you are better off looking at pl/proxy or dblink.  You may also be able to design functions and views along principles that work.  To be honest, pl/proxy is probably your best shot.